# Handling header in data buffer

Tags: c

I have a data buffer with following content:

```
00000000    20 7F 3E 15 38 34 37 2E 38 33 33 36 38 32 20 2F
00000010    20 31 33 2E 30 30 35 34 31 39 20 3E 20 20 20 20    
00000020    20 3E 20 4E 4F 20 47 50 53 20 44 41 54 41 20 20
00000030    20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

Now I want to use the 'real' data to process it in another function.

The 'real' data is everything after the first 5 bytes. The fifth byte, in this example 0x38, is the data length. How do I now scan the buffer for the header 0x20 0x7F 0x3E 0x15 and the data length byte and move the real data content to another buffer or maybe better, strip the current buffer to only the data content?

Note: I cannot allocate memory dynamically.
The buffer size is always 60 bytes (including header).

Thx!

Comment: Uh, you say the "the 'real' data is everything after the first 5 bytes" and "the fifth byte is the data length". So why do you think you *need* to 'scan' the buffer for the header?

Comment: Because I want to know if the data I received is from the known source/device, therefore I need to check the header every time.

Comment: Do you still need the 1st five bytes after "stripping" the buffer?

Comment: Why strip the header off the data ? Just pass the pointer to the buffer to your function and process the data that starts from the 5th byte.

Comment: After checking the header, I don't need the information anymore, so the header could be stripped off.

Comment: `memmove(buffer, buffer + 5, 60 - 5)` strips the header.

Comment: @MichaelWalz You are absolutly right, I just had a weird 'solution'. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the original buffer contains at least 5 bytes:

```
#define CAPACITY UINT8_MAX
uint8_t buf[CAPACITY], newbuf[CAPACITY - 5];
...
int header_is_ok = 
    (buf[0] == 0x20 && buf[1] == 0x7F && buf[2] == 0x3E && buf[3] == 0x15);

if (header_is_ok) {
    uint8_t length = buf[4];

    if (length > 0 && length < CAPACITY - 5) {
        uint8_t *contents = buf + 5;
        memcpy(newbuf, contents, length);
    }
}
```

The `memcpy` would move the buffer to another location, once the beginning of the contents and the length are known.

Comment: For completeness you might like to define `newBuf` as well as `CAPACITY_OF_BUF`.

Comment: Hu, why `UINT8_MAX` and not just `60`?

Comment: Because `length` is a byte and can be `UINT8_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

My first contribution here on StackOverflow, hope u'll enjoy my help.

The answer above is good enough, but I'd like to input the way I'd do it. This will make it easy for you to keep track of the different parts in the header, and to separate the header from the data.

Cons is that you need less comments, easier to debug and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>


//! Structure defining the different parts in the buffer
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t part1;
        uint8_t part2;
        uint8_t part3;
        uint8_t part4;
        uint8_t length;
    }header;
    uint8_t fullHeader[5];

    uint8_t *data;
}tDataInfo;


//! Size of header (in bytes)
static const uint8_t sizeOfHeader = 5;


//! Dummy data buffer
static uint8_t dataBuffer[] =
{
    0x20, 0x7F, 0x3E, 0x15, 0x0B, 0x34, 0x37, 0x2E, 0x38, 0x33, 0x33, 0x36, 0x38, 0x32, 0x20, 0x2F
};


int main()
{
    tDataInfo dataInfo;
    uint8_t *dataPtr;
    uint8_t cnt;


    // Copy header information
    memcpy(&dataInfo.header, dataBuffer, sizeOfHeader);


    // Print out header information
    printf("part1: %x\n", dataInfo.header.part1);
    printf("part2: %x\n", dataInfo.header.part2);
    printf("part3: %x\n", dataInfo.header.part3);
    printf("part4: %x\n", dataInfo.header.part4);
    printf("length: %d\n\n", dataInfo.header.length);


    // Allocate space for the data
    dataInfo.data = malloc(dataInfo.header.length);

    // Point to first byte of data
    dataPtr = dataBuffer + sizeOfHeader;

    // Copy the data
    memcpy(dataInfo.data, dataPtr, dataInfo.header.length);

    // Print out the data
    for ( cnt = 0; cnt < dataInfo.header.length; cnt++ )
    {
        printf("byte %d: %x\n", cnt, *(dataInfo.data+cnt));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is resembles one of the previous, but is more functional. It implies that the machine use little endian format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

    typedef struct    //pseudo structure describing the header and the data
    {
        int_16 key;   //first 4 bytes as device key
        unsigned char length;    //length of data not including the 5 header bytes
        char  data[1]    //pseudo array of buffer data
    } DATA;

    #define KEY 0x153e7f20    //The first 4 bytes used as a key to check for device
    #define BUFSIZE 60        //buffer size

    // The function return TRUE if any data is transferred to the buffer
    BOOL ReadData(char *RawData, char *buf)
    {
         DATA *pdata = RawData;
         if (KEY != pdata->key)
             return FALSE;

         memcpy(buf, pdata->data, pdata->length <= BUFSIZE ? pdata->length : BUFSIZE);

         return TRUE;
    }
```